# git clone "RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer" (RESOLVED(

Tags: git

I tried to execute git clone command but I got this error:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

---

```
$ git clone --progress -v --depth 1 "https://gitlab.xxx.com/yyy/zzz.git" "C:\ddd\aaaa"
Cloning into 'C:\ddd\aaaa'...
POST git-upload-pack (190 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (199 bytes)
remote: Enumerating objects: 117, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (117/117), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (96/96), done.
remote: Total 117 (delta 13), reused 97 (delta 7)
Receiving objects:  97% (114/117), 35.62 MiB | 9.66 MiB/s 
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer
Receiving objects: 100% (117/117), 35.62 MiB | 9.64 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13), done.
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed with:

```
- git config --global http.sslBackend openssl
- git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
- git config --global http.sslVerify false 
- git clone --progress -v --depth 1 "https://xxxx.com"
```

Comment: `http.postbuffer` has no effect on clones and, [as the Git FAQ mentions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer), your system is very broken if it works.  Also, `http.sslVerify` being set to false won't fix the problem here (since you clearly don't have a TLS problem when connecting), but it does completely remove any security from the connection, allowing an attacker to arbitrarily modify and tamper with your connection.  Neither of those is a good option to set, in general.

Comment: Do you want also suggest a solution or you're able only to complain about what's wrong?

Comment: It could be that switching to OpenSSL fixed the problem for you and that's the solution.  However, there's no intrinsic reason that SChannel should not work, and the problem could lie elsewhere.  Or it could be that the shallow clone didn't trigger the problem, but a full clone would.  There are any of a dozen reasons why this might have fixed the problem for you, and I can't say why.  I can, however, say what is not going to solve the problem and what you should not use.